# Elasticsearch ranking aggregation with multiple terms query

Tags: elasticsearch, information-retrieval

tl;dr: Want to rank aggregations based on whether bucket key has used either of the search terms.

I have two indices documents and recommendations with the following mappings:

**Documents:**

```
{
    "id": string,
    "document_text" : string,
    "author" : { "name": string }
    ...other fields
}
```

**Recommendations:**

```
{
    "id": string,
    "recommendation_text" : string,
    "author" : { "name": string }
    ...other fields
}
```

The problem I am solving is to have top authors for query terms.

This works quite well with `multimatch` for a single query term like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "science",
      "fields": [
        "document_text",
        "recommendation_text"
      ],
      "type": "phrase",
    }

  },
  "aggs": {
    "search-authors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author.name.keyword",
        "size": 50
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top-docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I have multiple keywords, let's say `zoology, botany`, I want the aggregation ranking to place the authors who have talked about both zoology and botany higher than those who have used either of them.

having multiple multi_match with bool doesn't help since this isn't exactly an and/or situation.